# Is there any free C# component class to provide means for C# code to load IronRuby code from files?

Tags: c#, ironruby

I learned here stackoverflow that you can easily achieve bidirectional access between c# of a Win form and javascript loaded in a web browser control. Then let me ask whether you can do similar bidirectional access between C# and IronRuby using any free C# component? Although I searched how to do bidirectional access between the 2 languages in .net platform,any of them does not bring the same simpleness as the way I described first.

Comment: @oleksii Thank you very much.Your sample may imply that I need no extra components to do what I want. It helps me searching similar samples for IronRuby.

Comment: yeah there are a few interfaces (and probably default implementations for several languages) that allow running other languages from C#. If there is no default component that allows you running Iron Ruby, there might be independant libraries which implement interfaces and allow running Iron Ruby, if you find one don't forget to post an answer here.

Comment: @oleksii, what? I think you can't runt IronRuby *without* the CLR. That's the point of it being IronRuby and not normal Ruby.

Comment: @svick I probably didn't get you, I was talking about the dynamic invokation of Iron Ruby code (*not IL*) from C#. Any .NET language requires runtime, but my point was that if you want to run Iron Ruby code (again *not IL*) directly from C#, then there should be a bridge, that compiles that file into IL and execute it in CLR. I am aware of only one such bridge: C# <-> Iron Python. I am not sure that there is one for Iron Ruby, I guess it exists.

Comment: @oleksii, then I guess I did not understand you. You were talking about “using CLR with IronRuby”, that has nothing to do with C#.

Comment: @svick I had something in mind mind but didn't put it in correct words. I reread my first comment and it was indeed rubbish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@svick is right but I just want to elaborate with an example where data flows from C# to IronRuby and back.

```
var engine = Ruby.CreateEngine();
engine.ExecuteFile("../../test.rb");
dynamic ruby = engine.Runtime.Globals;
dynamic hello = ruby.Hello.@new("Hello from Ruby!");
hello.set_text(textBox1);
```

and the Ruby code in test.rb

```
class Hello
  def initialize text
    @text = text
  end

  def set_text text_box
    text_box.Text = @text
  end
end
```

PS. After installing IronRuby from http://ironruby.net/download/ I, for some reason, could only find the IronRuby.dll, IronRuby.Libraries.dll, and Microsoft.Scripting.dll in C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\
DS.

Comment: Thank you very much. The code works well in IronRuby 1.0. I will check objects of what C# classes are accessible within IronRuby.

Comment: The whole of .Net is accessible from IronRuby and you don't need any C# code to use them.

Answer (score 2):

The IronRuby library lets you do just that. Just reference the IronRuby.dll and IronRuby.Libraries.dll assemblies, add `using IronRuby;` and then you can do something like:

```
var engine = Ruby.CreateEngine();
var scope = engine.ExecuteFile(fileName);
```

You can then query the `scope` for certain variables, or get a list of all variables.

Comment: Thank you very much.Both 2 answers work well with IronRuby 1.0.